# как изменить заменёным словам цвет?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
var element = elements[i];

for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
    var node = element.childNodes[j];

    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var text = node.nodeValue;
        var replacedText = text.replace(/[word or phrase to replace 
 here]/gi, '[new word or phrase]');

        if (replacedText !== text) {

 element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText),node);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

это скрипт должен выделать слова и заменять их другими(этот скрипт для расширения)помогите пожалуста переделать его так чтоб он изменял цвет заменённых  слов скажем на красный

Comment: А какими признаками обладают зелёные слова? Скрипт, который вы  показываете, ищет строку.

Comment: он ишет слово потом его заменят на другое но как сделать чтоб заменёное слово было красным допустим

Comment: Как мы узнаем, что слово зелёное? \У него класс есть или инлайн-стиль может?

Comment: var replacedText = text.replace(/[word or phrase to replace 
 here]/gi, '<span style="color:green">[new word or phrase]</span>');

Comment: не работает выводиться весь текст он добавляет его как текст вместо того чтоб добавить как код

Comment: зачем дублировать вопрос????

Comment: может потому что я не нашел ответа и хочу чтоб люди увидели и помогли?

Comment: тебе только карму уменьшат

Comment: да мне екстеншен надо написать что меня сейчас меньше всего волнует это карма)

Comment: я увидел только второй вопрос, так что логика сработала)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том что вы создаете текстовый елемент, а вам нужно создавать елемент на основе разметки.

[Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/яблок/gi,'<span class="red">pineapple</span>');


            if (replacedText !== text) {
                  var div = document.createElement('div');
                  div.innerHTML = replacedText.trim();
                  element.replaceChild(div.firstChild, node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо тебе огромное <3<3<3 mykola