# помогите заменить слова на слова с цветом

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

style.css

```
.red{
 background-color: red;
 }
```

content.js

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/яблок/gi,'<span class="red">pineapple</span>');


            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видите добавляется в месте со спаном как сделать что спан применялся

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791590/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82

Comment: удалите один вопрос :)

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что вы создаете текстовый елемент, а вам нужно создавать елемент на основе разметки.

[Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/яблок/gi,'<span class="red">pineapple</span>');


            if (replacedText !== text) {
                  var div = document.createElement('div');
                  div.innerHTML = replacedText.trim();
                  element.replaceChild(div.firstChild, node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```